# How to assert the current URL?

Tags: selenium, yii, phpunit

I'm unittesting my Yii application with `PHPUnit` and `Selenium-server`.

**Code:**

```
class StartSurveyRedirectTest extends WebTestCase
{
  public $fixtures=array(
    'sessions'=>'SurveySession',
    'surveys' => 'Survey',
  );

  public function testActive() {
    $survey = $this->surveys('survey_active');
    $user_id = 1;
    $imid = 'nl1234-9876';
    $this->open('veldwerk/survey/redirect?survey_id=' . $survey->survey_id . 
        '&user_id=' . $user_id . 
        '&imid=' . $imid . 
        '&' . $survey->security_parameter_name . '=' . $survey->getSecurityParameterValue()
    );

    //assert if redirected
    $this->assertNotEquals($this->url(),TEST_BASE_URL . 
        'veldwerk/survey/redirect?survey_id=' . $survey->survey_id . 
        '&user_id=' . $user_id . 
        '&imid=' . $imid . 
        '&' . $survey->security_parameter_name . '=' . $survey->getSecurityParameterValue()
    );
  }
}
```

The result when I start the test:

```
There was 1 error:

1) StartSurveyRedirectTest::testActive

Method url not defined.

D:\workspace\Pi\framework\test\CWebTestCase.php:63
D:\workspace\Pi\protected\tests\functional\StartSurveyRedirectTest.php:27
D:\workspace\Pi\protected\tests\functional\StartSurveyRedirectTest.php:27

Caused by
BadMethodCallException: Method url not defined.

D:\workspace\Pi\framework\test\CWebTestCase.php:63
D:\workspace\Pi\protected\tests\functional\StartSurveyRedirectTest.php:27
D:\workspace\Pi\protected\tests\functional\StartSurveyRedirectTest.php:27
```

So what I really want to test is if the user has been redirected. I thought the easiest way was to check the URL but it turns out it doesn't work? While in the selenium docs and PHPUnit docs says it can..

Does the Yii framework does not support this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase_Driver` is an ancestor class of `WebTestCase` the Yii class I extend in my test.

`PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase_Driver` implements the method getLocation() which holds the current browser url. This allows me to use `$this->getLocation()`

[SeleniumTestCase_Driver class reference](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase/Driver.php)

**The result of my code:**

```
//assert if redirected
$this->assertNotEquals($this->getLocation(),TEST_BASE_URL . 
    'veldwerk/survey/redirect?survey_id=' . $survey->survey_id . 
    '&user_id=' . $user_id . 
    '&imid=' . $imid . 
    '&' . $survey->security_parameter_name . '=' . $survey->getSecurityParameterValue()
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using url as a method, try it as a property:

`$this->url`

I'm at work now and am able to check this out. I think the proper code for PHPUnit with Selenium is:

`$driver->getCurrentPageUrl();`

So it is a method from the driver instance.

Comment: Thanks, but `Unknown property 'url' for class 'StartSurveyRedirectTest'.` Remember I'm testing a Yii application

Comment: I've updated my answer with the correct path to get the url. Why does it matter that you are testing an app written in YII? The test themselves are not written in Yii right? I'm not sure what `StartSurveyRedirectTest` is but somewhere you should be creating a new instance of `WebDriver` and that variable is the one we need to call  `getCurrentPageUrl()` from. Make sense?

Comment: Thank you @ragamuffin for making me aware of the driver. I was able to figure that this driver is an instance of `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase_Driver` which let me figure out the answer